# Why can we do Wick rotations even if $\Delta<0$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

[image: 1]

The above page is from Schwartz QFT. Why can we do Wick rotations even if $\Delta<0$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Have you tried the analogous residue theorem calculation, as per Problem B.1? If you got stuck, edit in your calculations so we know how.

Answer (score 2):

Define $$ |\omega|~:=~\sqrt{\left||\vec{k}|^2+\Delta\right|}.$$
The denominator is then of the form
$$\begin{align}
(k^0_M)^2-(|\vec{k}|^2+\Delta-i\epsilon)~=~&
(k^0_M)^2-(\pm|\omega|^2-i\epsilon)\cr
~=~&\left\{\begin{array}{c} (k^0_M)^2-(|\omega|-i\epsilon)^2 \cr (k^0_M)^2-(i|\omega|-\epsilon)^2 \end{array}\right\}\cr 
~\text{if}~~& |\vec{k}|^2+\Delta~\left\{\begin{array}{c} \geq \cr   \leq \end{array}\right\}~0, 
\end{align}$$
respectively. Hence the poles are
$$ 
k^0_M~=~\left\{\begin{array}{c} \pm(|\omega|-i\epsilon)  \cr \pm(i|\omega|-\epsilon) \end{array}\right\} 
~\text{if}~~  |\vec{k}|^2+\Delta~\left\{\begin{array}{c} \geq \cr   \leq \end{array}\right\}~0. 
 $$

One may check that the poles in the complex $k^0_M$ plane in all cases stay in [quadrants](https://www.google.com/search?q=quadrant+complex+plane&tbm=isch) II and IV, and hence do not interfere with the [Wick rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick_rotation) $k^0_M=ik^0_E$ from Minkowskian (M) signature to Euclidean (E) signature, which takes place in quadrants I and III, cf. Fig. B.1 on top of p. 824.

Comment: I’m confused because the poles should be +/-sqrt(|k|^2 + Δ) -/+ . What if Δ < - |k|^2 ? Then the poles will be 100% imaginary and I don’t see how Wick rotation is possible

Comment: Nevermind, I think I can rewrite it so that it’s still a pole, but definitely in quadrants II and IV. Albeit away from the poles in  the Δ > 0 case

Comment: I updated the answer.